# Recommendations for an academic abstract template

Tags: templates, examples

Can you point me to some examples of stand-alone abstract layouts? (I mean abstract in the 'academic' context here). I am submitting an abstract to a conference which does not provide a template. They suggest submitting a word doc or pdf - and I wanted to use Latex to produce this.

I've search online and found [this](http://molspect.mps.ohio-state.edu/symposium/SamplAbstr.html) but not some of the associated files. I've previously used the IEEE one, and dislike it - I'm wondering if there are any other commonly used abstract templates that I have missed. The submission is to a scientific (engineering) conference and is 300-400 words.

Comment: I'm not sure how to post this to community wiki - but I think it is relevant there.

Comment: The usage of *abstract* can be quite confusing here, because people will first think you talk about the format of the `abstract` environment.

Comment: I tried to clarify it - should I remove the `abstract` tag also?

Comment: Much better. Yes the `{abstrac}` tag should be removed. The `{templates}` tag already does it IMHO.

Comment: Only mods can make questions CW (use the flag link to notify them). However, I don't think this question should be CW: there will be one answer that is the correct one (i.e. the one you end up using).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have almost abused the IFAC conference template by only invoking the abstract part as the following

```
\documentclass{ifacconf}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Analysis of very important things\thanksref{footnoteinfo}} 
\thanks[footnoteinfo]{The author acknowledges the difficulty of publishing results}
\author[First]{Name} 
\address[First]{Return to sender (e-mail: {mr.author@tex.com} )}
\begin{abstract} 
A result that does not use the ``novel" word in its abstract.
\end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

You can download the template from [here](http://ifac.papercept.net/conferences/support/tex.php). Hope that it suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks - I do like it. Do you know if there is an easy way of suppressing the lines above and below?

Comment: Well, I have now seen that it is not allowed to modify the code (stated on the starting lines in the comments). Nevertheless, if you know your way around, check out the lines 1027-1038 in the class file.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - that is a serious warning in the class file comments!

Answer (score 5):

If they want Word quality use the package `wordlike`! :-)
It produces documents almost as ugly then the original.

But now to be serious:
If you don't want to use the IEEE template (which is always I good way to go) and they don't provide an own template, simply design your own simple format to suit yourself and the conference. Concentration should be on the content anyway.

Here the simple class a colleague and me created for our *digests* (aka *abstracts*) for the Applied Power Electronic Conference (APEC). It did the job and both papers where accepted. Some extra stuff is commented out because I didn't needed it with my last paper, but it might come in handy.

```
\ProvidesClass{apecdigest}

\PassOptionsToClass{letterpaper}{article}%
\LoadClassWithOptions{article} % 12pt preferred, 10pt is minimum
\RequirePackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\RequirePackage[english]{babel}

\RequirePackage{mathptmx}

\RequirePackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

% Only allow figures on extra pages
%\renewcommand{\topfraction}{.001}
%\setcounter{topnumber}{0}
%\setcounter{bottomnumber}{0}
%\setcounter{totalnumber}{0}
%\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{.001}

%\renewcommand{\topfraction}{.85}%(=Maximum fraction of the page that can be occupied by floats at the top of the page)
%\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{.85}

%\RequirePackage[format=hang,justification=justified,font=sf,labelfont=bf,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

%\RequirePackage{subfigure}

%\clubpenalty = 10000
%\widowpenalty = 10000
%\displaywidowpenalty = 10000

\endinput
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but how do I use this?

Comment: Just safe it as `apecdigest.cls` and use it as class. Alternatively just copy it in your document, delete `\ProvidesClass` and remove `\LoadClassWithOptions` with `\documentclass`. This file is minimal but packed as class (which loads `article`) so it can be shared by more then one digest.