# Separate authors when using IFAC template

Tags: templates

Following the answer given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10750/13294) about how to generate an academic abstract, I'm using the `ifacconf` class ([IFAC](http://www.ifac-control.org/events/authors-guide)).

A PDF sample of how this class looks can be seen [here](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sharelatex.com%2Ftemplates%2Fjournals%2Fifac-conferences-and-symposia%2Fifac-conferences-and-symposia.pdf&ei=gJ8BVa_SHpPfsATrg4LABg&usg=AFQjCNHtLJ0ir-38KqEy8z1xoCRynvdYww&sig2=oocABDNkha_AMMAb2bWpUA&bvm=bv.87920726,d.cWc) (full package can be downloaded [here](http://www.ifac-control.org/events/resolveuid/b0e4734736878819db179d76290a8f78)), I show below a print of the first page:

[image]

Notice how there is no separation between the authors, no comma, no `\&`, nothing. Personally, I think that doesn't look good.

So the question is: how do I add a comma or an `and` or something to separate authors?

MWE taken from the answer mentioned above:

```
\documentclass{ifacconf}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Analysis of very important things\thanksref{footnoteinfo}} 
\thanks[footnoteinfo]{The author acknowledges the difficulty of publishing results}
\author[First]{Name1} 
\author{Name2}
\author{Name3}
\address[First]{Return to sender (e-mail: {mr.author@tex.com} )}
\begin{abstract} 
A result that does not use the ``novel" word in its abstract.
\end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why can't you just write say ``\author[First]{Name1} 
\author{, Name2}
\author{\& Name3}``? I compiled and that seems to work for me. You can even add space before names using ``\quad`` or ``\hspace*{}``

Comment: Because it doesn't look right. I was after something a bit more professional looking.

Comment: Have you to use this style because you want to submit a paper there? Then avoid changings, I guess they will not accept them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the class is meant for submissions and the style chosen by the publisher should not be discussed

Comment: @egreg I was not using the class for submission, I was using it to generate a general abstract and I liked the format.